# Number of ways of posting 5 letters

Tags: algebra-precalculus, permutations

Find the number of ways of posting 5 letters in 7  mail Boxes.

my answer comes out to be $5^7$ but textbook states it to be $7^5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $7$ locations where you can put each letter. Thus we have $7$ choices $5$ times and the answer is $7^5$. If you explain your reasoning for choosing $5^7$, I might be able to help further.

Comment: i made 7 blanks to reason out. each blank can be filled with 5 ways

Comment: The problem with this argument is that if you fill one of the $7$ blanks in one way, you limit your choices for the other $6$ blanks. For example, if you choose $5$ for one of the blanks, then all the others are forced to be $0$. Thus, $5^7$ is overcounting

Comment: huh ? please elaborate. by 5 you mean 5 ways or 5th letter

Comment: Sorry, I mean you put 5 letters in one box

Comment: how is this overcounting

Comment: Because in your way, you could put 5 letters in each mailbox. This is not an actual possibility.

Comment: The answer of $5^7$ corresponds to each mail box choosing exactly one letter to be put in it, regardless of what is put in the other boxes. The answer of $7^5$ corresponds to each letter choosing exactly one box to be put in, regardless of where the other letters are put.

Comment: how can i have 5^7 as there is only 1 copy of letter..same letter can't go in 2 different boxes. is that right?

Comment: Yes. That is correct, thus you have to choose a mailbox for each letter and not the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

Think if there was still $5$ letters, but only one mail box. Would that make it $5^1$ possibilities, or $1^5$?

Think if there were still seven mail boxes, but only one letter. Would that make it $7^1$ possibilities, or $1^7$?

Now can you see how the answer is $7^5$ rather than $5^7$?

Comment: answer is okay but appears more of guess work for me..

Comment: Its comparing it to simpler cases for you to see the error of your reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

You have to post letters in box. Not box in letters.

So you picked first letter you have 7 options. For second letter you have again 7 options. So on...

Then we have,

$7 \times 7 \times 7 \times 7 \times 7 = 7^5$